# How to fetch the department name for a particular User from Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[My Database in firebase is in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPEq2.png)

I need that if a user login then for that particular UID I need his associated department name. So How to take the department name as a String.I use this code to fetch department name

```
 String u_id=auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
 mdatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(u_id).child("department");
                         user=mdatabase.getKey();
```

By this i don't get the result.Please provide solution

```
public class LoginPage extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnLogin;
private TextView ForgetText;
private EditText userText,PassText;
private String UserEmail,UserPassword;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthlistener;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private DatabaseReference mdatabase;
public String departmental;
//private Spinner dropdown;
Variables v=new Variables();
private String username,user;
private Intent i;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);


    auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    ForgetText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    userText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email2);
    PassText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password2);
    progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SignIn();
        }
    });

    ForgetText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginPage.this,ForgotPassword.class));
        }
    });
}
```

public void SignIn(){

```
   UserEmail=userText.getText().toString().trim();
    UserPassword=PassText.getText().toString().trim();
if (UserEmail.isEmpty()){
Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,"Please Enter the Email 
Id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if (UserPassword.isEmpty())
{
Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,"Please enter Valid 
Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else {
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(UserEmail, UserPassword)
        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginPage.this, new 
OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If 
sign in succeeds
                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic 
to handle the
                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // there was an error

                    Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,"Error in 
 logging!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else
```

{
 if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().equals(v.admin))
                            startActivity(new 
    Intent(LoginPage.this,AdminUser.class));
                        else {
                            String u_id = 
    auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

```
                       mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(u_id).child("department");
                        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                String  department = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                        };
                        mdatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,u_id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,departmental,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        /*i = new Intent(LoginPage.this, LoggedIn.class);
                        i.putExtra("hello_user",department);
                        startActivity(i);*/
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
            }
        });
```

}

```
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
String u_id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(u_id).child("department");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String department = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        Log.d("TAG", department);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
mdatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Gives error:-Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Comment: This means that in your `mdatabase`, one of the arguments of `child()` methods is null. Have you checked the `u_id`? Is it `null`? This the only one which can be `null`.

Comment: its not null.I've checked it.Actually I have to pass this department string in another activity there it shows null

Comment: Now i CHecked the string department is null.It does not fetch the value of that particular user

Comment: If the `u_id` in `not null` and as you say `department` is null, check the spelling in both places, your database and your code. The code must work for sure.

Comment: And check also is that the `u_id` is correct for the coresponding user with which you are testing.

Comment: mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(u_id).child("department");

Comment: This code is correct. Can you Log the `u_id` to asure that is not null?

Comment: Ya i toasted the U_id.ITS not null

Comment: Now are you logging the `department` names in the logcat?

Comment: Sir 1st time it is taking null then when i used it again it gives me the department of previously loggedin user

Comment: I declared the string department globally because i have to pass this as parameter.

Comment: It is wrong to declare it globally because `onDataChange()` is called asynchronously. So you need to use this string only in that method.

Comment: If i have to use that particular string in other method then what can i do?

Comment: Please check my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612171/arraylist-gets-empty-after-first-snapshot).

Comment: Don't get the point.I am adding my whole code of that class Please check

Comment: You cannot simply call that particular string in another method.You are using `Toast` outside that method. Try to use this code: `Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,departmental,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` inside the `onDataChange()`.

Comment: You didn't get my point.See i have to pass this Department String to another activity.So please tell what i have to do?

Comment: You need to move this lines: `i = new Intent(LoginPage.this, LoggedIn.class);
                        i.putExtra("hello_user",department);
                        startActivity(i);` inside `onDataChange()` method