# Firebase Database Datasnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `firebase` database from which I save and retrieve data from, to and from. I know how `datasnapshot` works inside an `addValueEventListener`. The problem is that this is only called or triggered when the `firebase` database detects change in its data. I only want to access data and read it to be able to store it in an arraylist or the same thing.

I have a code like this:

```
public void foo(){
    DatabaseReference x= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("x");

    reservations.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String userID = client.getId();
            for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if(snap.child("someId").equals(someId)) number++;
                if(snap.child("userID").getValue().equals(client.getId())){
                    isAlreadyReserved = true;   // if user has already reserved the item
                    alreadyReserved();
                    break;
                }
                Log.e("isAlreadyReserved: ", isAlreadyReserved+"");
                numberOfReservations++;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    if(isAlreadyReserved) {
        alreadyReserved();
    }
    else if(number == numberOfCopies){
        // material is no longer available
        OtherActivity.showMaterialUnavailable();
    }
    else{
        Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
        reservation.setBookId(this.bookId);
        reservation.setResID((numberOfReservations+1)+"");
        reservation.setUserID(client.getId());
        String key = reservations.push().getKey();
        reservations.child(key).setValue(reservation);

        Log.e("Reservations: ", "reserve successful");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.reservationSuccess_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.reservationSuccess_body);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

You can see that inside `onDataChange` I only count materials and set some flags, which I can supposedly do outside the `ValueEventListener`.
But I notice that this is faulty because `onDataChange` is called only when writing to the `Firebase` database occurs. Which should not be the case.

What can I do to loop through the values inside the `DatabaseReference x` without calling `onDataChange`, or without using `DataSnapshot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot loop inside a `DatabaseReference` without using a `listener`. When we are talking about Firebase, we are talking only about `listeners`. So in order to get those values, you need to use a listener and than get the data out from the `dataSnapshot`.

What i think your problem is in your case, is that `onDataChange` method is called in an asynchronously way. This means that everything you are doing outsite this method is actually executed before `onDataChange` method has been called. So in order to understand what is actually going on, please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576441/querying-data-from-firebase) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723139/wait-firebase-async-retrive-data-in-android). Reading this posts, will teach you how to `query` data in Firebase and how to `retrieve data from Firebase asynchronously`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Tho I have already solved my problem. I used an `AsyncTask` to make a REST call to the `Firebase` realtime database, and used it to pre-process the data that I need before firing the `onDataChange()` method of its `ValueEventListener`. This way, I can call the `onDataChange()` in just the right time after the data processing.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the values of DatabaseReference x, you should use addListenerForSingleValueEvent

```
    x.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            //do something
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

as mentioned in the firebase documentation:

> public void addListenerForSingleValueEvent (ValueEventListener
>   listener)
>
> Add a listener for a single change in the
>   data at this location. This listener will be triggered once with the
>   value of the data at the location.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I think the problem still remains. This `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` function is only going to be called when the `DatabaseReference x` performs changes on the Firebase Realtime Database.

I need it to go like:

`Fetch data from Realtime DB` -> `Process data` -> `Perform necessary changes on Realtime DB`

Instead, it goes like:
`Perform changes in order to trigger listener` -> `Fetch data from listener` -> `Process data` -> `Perform changes in Realtime DB`

Comment: This event happens only one time, and after you set it, it doesn't happen only after data change. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried it. It does not solve the problem. It still needs a data change to perform the process. I need to read the values first before performing data changes.

Comment: This is wired, that worked for me. When do you call the foo method? maybe there is a problem around that.

Comment: I call it inside an alert dialog's onclick listener. the error is not there. im already thinking of using a rest call in an asynctask only to view the contents and take the data that i need, _instead of_ performing a data change to read the data, then doing another data change.

Comment: Have you checked that the data ref on wich you set the listener exists?

Comment: Yes, it exists. I can fetch data cleanly from the Firebase realtime database, but that is not the case. Thanks for answering, I already resorted to using an asynctask for a rest call. Thank you.