# android firebase reads all the database

Tags: android, listview, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to read a specific child in Firebase which i named Tags. the problem is, i just can't put the object from tags (dados.getValue) into a ArrayList to later populate in my ListView.

I know is simple, sorry about that, ut i am new here in android

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_taglist);

        tags = new ArrayList<>();
        tagList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tagsList);

        tagsRefs = FirebaseConfig.getFireBase();
        tagsRefs.child("tags").child("categorias");

        tagsRefs.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dados : dataSnapshot.child("tags").getChildren()) {
                    System.out.println("tag EXTRAIDA NO taglist " + dados.getValue());
                     dados.getValue();   //HOW CAN I PUT THIS INTO AN ARRAY TO LATER ADD IN MY ArrayList tags?? 
                    String tagS = dados.getValue(String.class);
                    tags.addAll(tagS);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        tagAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                android.R.id.text1,
                tags);


        tagList.setAdapter(tagAdapter);

        tagList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                selectedTag = (String) tagList.getItemAtPosition(position);

                setSelectedTag(selectedTag);

            }
        });


    }
```

here is my database:
[h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPBxS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `onDataChange()` method is called asynchronously. This means that the statement that adds tags to your `list` is executed before `onDataChange()` method has been called. That's why your list is empty outside that method. So in order to use that lists, you need to use it inside the `onDataChange()`.

For other approach, please visit this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576441/querying-data-from-firebase) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Hope it helps.

Comment: tks so much for the advice, the problem was my tags declaration in 
            ArrayList tagss = (ArrayList) dados.getValue();