# Dealing with dynamic keys in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the structure as follows:

> Courses>Course>Programme>Sem>{SubjectName}>total>attendance>orderbykey.equalsTo(uid)

I have a issue iterating through the subjects where the key is dynamic, like for for eg. here the key for one is **PA** and other is **PC** and it will be dynamically pushed by the user and will be different for every Sem.

I have tried this:

```
Query subjectQuery = mDatabaseRef.child("courses/"+user.getCourse()+"/"+user.getProgramme()+"/"+user.getSem()+"/subjects");
    subjectQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Log.d("subjects", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
                sub = new Subject[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];
                int i = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot subjectSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    sub[i] = new Subject(subjectSnapShot.getValue().toString());
                    Log.d("subject_class","sub["+i+"] : "+sub[i].getName());
                    i++;
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Data Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(sub.length), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

As The Listener is `Async` the toast makes the app crash and gives a **`NullPointerException`** as the `sub` is still null

edited: the reason for this is to get the subjects and pass it to the fragment. please suggest if anyone has a better way to go around the problem

[image: Firebase Structure Here]

Comment: Your question title is very different from your actual problem. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43576696/4916627) will help you understand and solve your problem.

Comment: @andrekool Well i have issue iterating through dynamic key values so this is a snippet which i wrote to get the key values before and pass it to my fragment, else i would have have to nest addListenerForSingleValueEvent or ValueEventListener which makes no sense as it would mean if the head listens a change then only it will detect a change in the nested ones. Could you suggest something better to iterate through the subjects first?

Comment: Keys will be dynamically pushed by the user! How you gonna ensure that keys be unique?! Because **keys are always unique within their context**.

Comment: @MuhammadAliJr In my app only certain users can write these keys and on their side i will keep a check whether their the keys are not repeating using the snapshot.getKey()